# Open files with one click using python

Tags: python, hyperlink, operating-system, pathlib

I made this code which shows the titles of files from my computer using os and pathlib.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

class Buscador:
    def Busca():
        opcao = str(input('Por qual palavra deseja buscar o documento? '))
        for file in os.listdir("/home/paulo/Documentos"):
            if file.endswith(".pdf"):
                file_name = Path(file).stem
                if opcao in file_name:
                    print(os.path.join(file_name))
                    print(' ')

Buscador.Busca()
```

I'd like to complement it by leaving the titles clickable, like a link. Clicking on the title would open the file

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is you can click the path to open the file location from the output section, then this is done through your code editor or IDE.

Edit:
I made this code which will scan a certain directory on my PC for files, if the result is a file it will will print the path in the format

```
C:\Users\John\Desktop\test.txt
```

If you want to open the file(using Visual Studio Code), just ctrl+click the output and it will open the file in a new tab.

The code:

```
import os

directory = r'path'    #The path to the folder containing the file

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        print(f)
```

Comment: I don't want to click on the path, I want to click on the file name that appears in the search output and open that file

Comment: Ok, now I understand what do you mean, but I think this problem can be fixed by using a different code editor/IDE

Comment: I tried something like this with VSCode, I made a code which will print out the path to a .txt file, ctrl+click the output and it will open the file

Comment: Can you show me the code for doing this?